# How can I filter a specific column of a dataframe using OOP?

Tags: python, pandas, class, oop

I have created a class called `Settings()`

```
class Settings():
      
    def data(self,sheet):
        return{sheet:data_dict[sheet]}
```

My `data(self,sheet)` method takes in an excel file and and returns the sheet name and the data of the excel file as a dictionary like this:

`{sheet_name:sheet_name df, sheet_name2:sheet_name2 df,}`

The df's of the individual sheets have a column called "RULE_ID", where all of the values begin with "AML-" and then contain a further string, like "CLF-ALL" or "EFT-ECT" for example.

I am looking to create a method of the `Settings()` class called `get()` where I can filter on the RULE_ID columns on each of the individual sheet_names/df's and retrive the data that corresponds to the RULE_ID I am filtering on

I have played around with the following code but having no luck, any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Something like; iterate through each dataframe, filter the correct data from each df, then combine those together?

```py
import pandas as pd

def get(self, rule_id: str) -> pd.DataFrame:

    sheets = {'df1': x, 'df2': y}
    filtered_frames = []

    for name, df in sheets.items():
        print('Processing {name}'.format(name=name))
        filtered = df[df['RULE_ID'] == rule_id]
        filtered_frames.append(filtered)
    
    return pd.concat(filtered_frames)
```

Comment: thank you for your help so far. I have edited my question to hopefully make it clearer for you?